# Getting the value of a variable inside a while statement - PHP

Tags: php, while-loop

I can't get the value of a variable inside a while loop.
Here's my code:

```
function checkLogin($username, $password) {
        global $dbh;            
        global $queryPassword;

        $query2 = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM employee_accounts WHERE username='$username' AND `password`='$password'; ");
        $query2 ->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        while($row=$query2->fetch()) {
            $queryUsername = $row['username'];
            $queryPassword = $row['password'];
        }

        if(password_verify($password, $queryPassword)) {

            echo '<script>alert("Success ");
            windows: location="../../index.php";</script>';
        } else {
            echo '<script>alert("fail ");
            windows: location="../../index.php?v='.$queryPassword.'";</script>';
        }


    }
```

When I put the $queryPassword in the url, the value is empty. Your suggestions and solutions will be very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: [You need to prevent SQL Injection!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Is the stored password hashed or plain text? Hard to tell due to the confusion in what you're doing with it.

Comment: The stored password is hashed. @developerwjk

Comment: I agree with @JayBlanchard; in addition to needing to prepare your statement to avoid SQL injection, it also appears you are calling JavaScript eval() on the response, which is also dangerous. Answering this question would be irresponsible unless you re-engineer for security and restate.

Comment: ^ Also trying to redirect with the password in a parameter like `?v=password` is a bad idea. You might want to use a param like `?error=true` to tell there was an authentication error, but certainly not to put the password there.

Comment: Yeah, I know that. But I just put it there to see if the variable $queryPassword has a value. @developerwjk

Comment: use var_dump() if you want to check a variable's content.

Comment: I used var_dump and the return is null.

Answer (score 0):

**Dont** use `global` for your password! That can cause problems with maintaining. change it to another type like private, or protected.

and also change your query to something more secure like this,

```
 $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM employee_accounts WHERE username= :user AND `password`= :pass; ");
 $stmt->execute(array(':user'=> $username ,':pass'=> $password ));
 $query2 ->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

This way the user inputs are escaped.

Comment: Still only a partial answer. The password is stored hashed, but this will be querying as if its stored in plain text. You need to run `password_hash()` on the password before doing this query.

Comment: Also this doesn't address the problem of how usernames should be unique in a table with a `unique` constraint, meaning there should be no need for a `while` loop but instead an `if` statement.

Comment: And it doesn't touch the issue of trying to redirect in Javascript when it ought to be done in PHP.

Comment: yeah I missed all those cause of focusing on the question. please revise my answer appropriately to your perspective.

Comment: Still doesn't work. I just want to get the value of the variable $queryPassword inside the while-loop.